# Netmiko - multiple outputs in different files

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

I want outputs from multiple commands, but outputs per command must be saved in different file. How can I split the outputs per command?

```
display_commands = ['display clock', 'display users']
output = ''
for command in display_commands:
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**router)
    output += net_connect.send_command(command, delay_factor=2)
```

Comment: output must be a list. So every outupu will be a new element in the list. output = [], output.append(blablabla)

Comment: thanks, do you have any sample? I can split he commands, I want to split the outputs and write them to different cells in excel

Comment: can someone help how to write the each output to different column in excel? I can write all output in one cell properly but not different cells.